# Login failed with CSRF Verification, even with token in payload?

Tags: python, authentication, request

I have the csrf middleware token in my payload however I am still getting this message:

"CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a '
Referer header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. Th
is header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser i
s not being hijacked by third parties."

```
import requests
from lxml import html

LOGIN_URL = "https://gyrosco.pe/login/email/"
URL = "https://gyrosco.pe/dashboard/"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token =         list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']/@value")))[0]

    # Create payload
    payload = {
    "email": "email",
    "password": "pass",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "token"
    }


    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers =         dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    #this prints out 403
    print(result.status_code)

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))

    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
```

Comment: where do you set the referer header?

Comment: Just updated with a different one, still having the same 403 issues though

Comment: Have you tried using different referrer urls? The error does state there is an issue with the url being used?

Comment: This code, as currently formatted, will not run. Either everything after the `authenticity_token = ...` line is mis-indented in your question, or your code is fundamentally broken.  Update your question if it's just an indenting issue.

Comment: Merely an indenting issue, just updated now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: I have the csrf middleware token in my payload

**You, haven't**, your `payload` has to look like this:

```
    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "email": "email",
        "password": "pass",
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": authenticity_token
    }
```

Should also work without `headers=`:

```
    # Perform login
    r = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - requests:2.11.1***